# Add extra validations to user signup

Tags: validation, form-validation

I need to add extra validations to user signup page. Currently user can enter characters to phone and fax fields. I want to prevent that from happening. How can I add those jquery parts? Where should I add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento already has validation for phone and fax numbers. This can be done by adding one of the following classes to the fields you want to validate

`validate-phoneStrict`, `validate-phoneLax` or `validate-fax`

More on validation can be found here: http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Comment: is there a way to show error messages also?

Comment: That is done automatically if everything is set correct

Comment: ah yeah. template I'm using added .validation-advice { display: none !important; } to their css. that was the issue. thanks